# Not return HTML back in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got my chathub like this

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string Message)
    {
        if(Message.Length > 0)
        {
            string Name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(Name, Message);
        }
    }
}
```

problem is that if the user enters a message like

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

it will be returned to the chat like

**Hello**

How can I make it just return `<strong>Hello</strong>`?

**Where I display (JS)**

```
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {


    $('#chat-table').append(name + ': ' + message);

};
```

Comment: Show the code how you are displaying the message ?

Comment: Added code that shows how I display

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text`

```
$('#chat-table').text(name + ': ' + message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this

```
Clients.All.broadcastMessage(Name, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Message));
```